# Is there any way to extract scala.html source code from a jar file?

Tags: java, scala, jar, decompiler

I have been trying to get the source code of scala.html from the jar file. But when I use normal decompilers I get java files but I need complete source file scala.html file is it possible to retrieve source code?

Comment: There seems to be some context missing here.What is "the source code of scala.html"?

Comment: Actually, I lost the source code of my application I have only jar files. I tried to decompile the jar files I retrieved the JS files and JAVA files but my views folder is containing java files but I need scala.html files is it possible to retrieve those using java files which generated while decompiling.

Comment: “I lost the source code,” ouch! You have my sympathy. Anyway, this appears to be a Twirl question. I believe the answer to your question is no. Twirl converts `.scala.html` files to Scala code, then that Scala code gets compiled to bytecode. The first step isn't reversible (unless you write your own decompiler, which would be difficult).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have extracted raw data of HTML code from Java files and cleaned up the code and recreated the pages.